# SOQL query to fetch N number of related records

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

We are having on complex self relation that there will be n number of related records for single record saying

Task 1 will have one sub task 1
Sub task 1 will have sub sub task 1
sub sub task will have sub sub sub task1
So on and there is no end for end.

If I update one value in Task 1 like start date then that value has to be updated untill the end tree.
Is there a way to find all the records in one go using SOQL so that I can update all the records in one shot?

We already created one flow to update the records but since nested childs are being updated its hitting the governor limit and trying to move to trigger but not able to get the records through SOQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" you cannot.

If you are traversing down the hierarchy, note the following from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm):

> In API version 57.0 and earlier, only two levels of parent-to-child relationship can be specified in a query.
>
> In API version 58.0 and later, up to five levels of parent-to-child relationship can be queried via REST and SOAP query calls for standard and custom objects. SOQL queries with five level parent-to-child relationships aren't supported for big objects, external objects, or in Apex, Bulk API, and Bulk API 2.0.

If you are trying to navigate "up" the hierarchy, from a child through its parents and further ancestors, SOQL supports currently 5 levels.

So regardless of the direction you try to traverse, it's impossible to process the whole hierarchy in one go if you have an arbitrary number of levels.

This sort of task will require use of a batch or queueable with appropriate tracking of where you've got to in the processing, and repeated querying as you navigate the tree.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I got it through queueable